# UserSensor.builder() Android Things

Tags: android

Like seen [here](https://developer.android.com/things/sdk/drivers/sensors.html), I have been following tutorials to create an accelerometer driver for my raspberry pi 3 with android things:

```js
public static UserSensor build(final Accelerometer lsm9DS0) {
        return UserSensor.builder()
                .setType(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER)
                .setName("LSM9DS0")
                .setVendor("")
                .setVersion(DRIVER_VERSION)
                .setRequiredPermission(DRIVER_REQ_PERM)
                .setPower(DRIVER_POWER)
                .setResolution(DRIVER_RESOLUTION)
                .setMaxRange(DRIVER_MAX_RANGE)
                .setMinDelay(DRIVER_MIN_DELAY)
                .setMaxDelay(DRIVER_MAX_DELAY)

                .setUuid(UUID.randomUUID())
                .setDriver(new UserSensorDriver() {
                    @Override
                    public UserSensorReading read() throws IOException {
                        final float[] result = lsm9DS0.getAccelerations();
                        return new UserSensorReading(
                                result,
                                SensorManager.SENSOR_STATUS_ACCURACY_HIGH);
                    }                   
                })
                .build();
```

I noticed that in devpreview 0.2 this method works fine for me, it registers all it reads and sends me results but when i use this specific method:

```js
        sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        if (sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) != null){
            Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: hay acelerometro");
        }
        else{
            Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: no hay acelerometro");
        }
```

It brings back null, even thought it does work and sends me results.

Then I tried updating developer preview to 0.4.1 but this part in my code:

.***builder***()   shows red and won't run saying "Cannot resolve method 'builder()' "

Anyone has any idea why?
Thanks in advance.